Stop NaviationLink overriding DisclosureGroup ontap gesture
I have the following SwiftUI view:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var items = [1, 2]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    DisclosureGroup(content: {
                        Text("Extra content for item \(item)")
                    }, label: {
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink {
                                DetailView()
                            } label: {
                                Text("View Details")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I press anywhere within the DisclosureGroup, I would like the "Extra content" to show. When I press specifically on the "View Details" button, I would like to navigate to the DetailView.
However, at the moment, the NavigationLink seems to be somehow overriding the ontap gesture of the DisclosureGroup. If I click anywhere on the DisclosureGroup, it navigates to DetailView - only showing the "Extra content" if I explicitly click on the DisclosureGroup's arrow.
I tried many of the answers in this question:
While changing List to ScrollView does work, it also messes up the padding, and I am not sure if there is a clean way to apply it to the ScrollView (if Apple changes the List styling in the future, I want my View to update automatically without changing the code).
Changing the buttonStyle to .borderless doesn't stop the NavigationLink from overriding the ontap gesture.
I cannot use a hidden NavigationLink with selected or isActive, because these are deprecated in iOS 16.
Meanwhile, embedding the NavigationLink inside a button doesn't navigate to the DetailView - it just performs the button's action instead.

You can use the iOS 16 way of programmatic navigation, along with a Button to trigger it. Use one of these:

navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)
navigationDestination(item:destination:)
navigationDestination(for:destination:) and a navigation path

Only the latter two works if the destination depends on the item you are "looping through" in the ForEach, which is likely the case in your situation.
Showing the three ways in order:
let items = [1, 2]
@State private var presented = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Extra content for item \(item)")
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Button("View Details") {
                            presented = true
                        }
                        .tint(.primary) // remove the default tint of the button
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $presented) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

Or
let items = [1, 2]
// in reality the items are probably not Ints - replace this with whatever type of thing you are showing details of
@State private var selectedItem: Int?
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Extra content for item \(item)")
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Button("View Details") {
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                        .tint(.primary)
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(item: $selectedItem) { item in
            DetailView(for: item)
        }

    }
}

Or
let items = [1, 2]
@State private var navigationPath: NavigationPath
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Extra content for item \(item)")
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Button("View Details") {
                            navigationPath.append(item)
                        }
                        .tint(.primary)
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // in reality the items are probably not Ints - replace this with whatever type of thing you are showing details of
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { item in
            DetailView(for: item)
        }

    }
}

